# QWebEnginePage.print with QPrintPreviewDialog results in empty preview

Tags: python, printing, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qprintpreviewdialog

I have a program that used to use `QWebKit` to show and print custom generated HTML reports in a dialog and now, I want to convert the whole thing to `QWebEngine`. Everything works fine so far, only printing doesn't!

Up to now I used `QWebView.print()` to hand the whole HTML data over to a `QPrintPreviewDialog` which wasn't a problem at all. Now, from what I understand, I thought I'd have to use `QWebEngineView.QWebEnginepage.print(printer object, callback)` to achieve the same.

Sadly, everything I tried so far hasn't worked. The preview pane of the QPrintPreviewDialog always stays empty and the result which is given back to the callback after printing is done is always False - although the printer object is still valid the whole time, even in the callback.

I tried out different things, which worked somehow and therefor I think, the QWebEnginePage.print() function is buggy somehow or there is a bug in PyQt, but in fact, I don't and perhaps it is me doing something wrong.

Successful workarounds (which I don't like ;-) ):

1. Don't use `QPrintPreviewDialog`, but generate the output via `QWebEngineView.QWebEnginePage.printToPDF(filename)`: worked!
2. Generate a temporary `QTextedit` object and print this via `QPrintPreviewDialog`: also worked, but badly formatted HTML in my case...

Can someone tell me, if I'm assuming something wrong here or if there is a descent example on how to print HTML via `QPrintPreviewDialog` using `QWebEngineView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtWebEngine currently doesn't support printing to a print preview, see [QTBUG-57982](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57982). Printing to a QPrinter directly works though.

Comment: Many many thanks! Let's hope the'll fix it soon! Until then I use the QTextedit workaround.